# Python polling to log sensor data

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am writing a python script that polls two sensors using threading, which records the data from these sensors to a csv log file.  Each sensor records data at a different rate (sensor 1: 1 sample/second; sensor 2: 10 samples/second) - and are implemented with threading.Thread.  Ideally, every time sensor 2 makes a new reading, the data from both sensors would be recorded to the log file - or any variation on this.

My unfamiliarity with multithreading means I am not sure about best practice here and grappling to find a sensible way to implement this: the options I have considered are:

1. Have data logging as a separate thread, waiting for an event.  When sensor 2 takes a new reading, sensor 2 sets the event, and the logging occurs
2. data logging as a timer based separate thread, writing new data as it finds it
3. passing a data logging function as an argument for the sensor polling function

All of these options could be implemented but they all seem a bit clunky - what would you suggest is the most pythonic way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do threading if you want to read two inputs periodically.

Write some code to read object1 and do time.sleep(0.1), read it 10 times, do a counter to count number of reads and if counter == 10 then go and read object2 as well and then reset counter to 0. Put it all in while True loop.

I know you may say: but it is a reading in sequence object1 -> object2 but I want to read object1 and object2 in the same time.

If this is the case that you want to read both two sensors in exact same time and the diff of e.g. 0.00001s makes sense to you then go with multiprocessing / multithreading but try to understand how Python does it because I have heard various opinion that you can not achieve REAL multithreading with Python but I am not fully sury why. Is it because Python will force its internal bytecode compiler to execute one instruction at cpu thread? I do not know. I am not sure.

So, if this is the case then you may try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def f(name):
    while True:
        print(time.time())
        print('read sensor 1', name)
        time.sleep(1)

def d(name):
    while True:
        print(time.time())
        print('read sensor 2', name)
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=f, args=('sensor1',))
    p2 = Process(target=d, args=('sensor2',))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

but note the times:

```
1528966987.5038514
read sensor 1 sensor1
1528966987.5468514
read sensor 2 sensor2
1528966988.5038514
read sensor 1 sensor1
1528966989.5038514
read sensor 1 sensor1
1528966990.5038514
read sensor 1 sensor1
1528966991.5038514
read sensor 1 sensor1
1528966992.5038514
read sensor 1 sensor1
1528966992.5468514
read sensor 2 sensor2
1528966993.5038514
read sensor 1 sensor1
1528966994.5038514
read sensor 1 sensor1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

There is a small difference (0.043):

```
1528966992.5038514
read sensor 1 sensor1
1528966992.5468514
read sensor 2 sensor2
```